# Merging TFS Team Project Collections

Tags: team-project

Is it possible to merge 2 different team project collections under TFS 2010, while keeping all version history (changeset numbers can change, since else there will be overlap problems in the numbering). e.g.

```
Team Project Collection A
  Team Project A
  Team Project B
Team Project Collection C
  Team Project C
```

And I want to end up with:

```
Team Project Collection A
  Team Project A
  Team Project B
  Team Project C
```

And keeping the version history (all different checkins) of Team Project C, so I can still revert to a previous version if needed, view changes etc.

As a follow up: is it also possible to split Team Project Collection A in 2 seperate collections (again keeping the history).

I can see several scenarios in which the setup initially planned fails to meet all requirements after a while (like common code for merging or size/seperation of concerns to split up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merge team project collections in TFS 2010. There are two many conflicts: changeset numbers, work item IDs, builds, test results, etc.

You can split a team project collection to multiple collections though. Here is the [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236915.aspx) about organizing the team project collections.

Answer (score 1):

TFS Integration Platform may help you to move projects but as the documentation clearly states, "it is a lossy transfer"